# Running JSCover in combination with Jasmine and Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, jasmine, jscoverage

I managed to set up JScover 0.2.0 on my Windows 7 to the point where I get to page on `http://localhost:8080/jscoverage.html`, and I can see test coverage for example working.

Jasmine test that I am attempting to run with JSCover for staters is `'jasmine-ObjectTreeStructure-Tests.js'` file that is in `/OnTheMoveWebFiles/js` folder of my project. Jasmine other libraries and test files all reside in this same folder.
I normally run jasmine tests by running project in debug mode, then navigating to `http://localhost:57263/FeatureDev/JavaScriptTestsWithDependencies.aspx`.
This page contains jasmine, jquery, ... other dependencies and many jasmine test .js files that need to be tested.
How do I go around integrating JSCover into my `JavaScriptTestsWithDependencies.aspx` file so that it would check code coverage. 
`JavaScriptTestsWithDependencies.aspx` is very basic.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {

        "use strict";

        var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
        jasmineEnv.updateInterval = 250;

        var htmlReporter = new jasmine.HtmlReporter();
        jasmineEnv.addReporter(htmlReporter);

        jasmineEnv.specFilter = function (spec) {
            return htmlReporter.specFilter(spec);
        };

        var currentWindowOnload = window.onload;
        window.onload = function () {
            if (currentWindowOnload) {
                currentWindowOnload();
            }

            execJasmine();
        };

        function execJasmine() {
            jasmineEnv.execute();
        }
    })();
</script>
```

I have tried running JSCover in [inverted mode](http://tntim96.github.io/JSCover/manual/manual.xml#invertedMode)  `window.open('path/to/jscoverage.html');`
by adding

```
        window.open('http://localhost:8080/jscoverage.html');
        function execJasmine() {
            jasmineEnv.execute();
        }
```

just before execJasmine method, but that only opened jscoverage.html in popup with blank url.

**Question:** where and how do I plug in JSCover into this, and if it's not possible what are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I managed to set up JScover 0.2.0

Firstly, why not grab the latest version from https://sourceforge.net/projects/jscover/files/?

> I normally run jasmine tests by running project in debug mode, then navigating to `http://localhost:57263/FeatureDev/JavaScriptTestsWithDependencies.aspx`

OK, in that case you can't use JSCover in server mode. To get the JavaScript instrumented, so that it will work, you either have to run JSCover in [proxy mode](http://tntim96.github.io/JSCover/manual/manual.xml#proxyMode), or instrument the JavaScript manually using the file-system mode before going to `http://localhost:57263/FeatureDev/JavaScriptTestsWithDependencies.aspx`. There are examples for both approaches [here](https://github.com/tntim96/JSCover/tree/master/examples).

Comment: I got latest 1.0.7 JScover and choose proxy approach, I am running proxy from JSCover-1.0.7\examples\localStorage-proxy  jscover-proxy.bat file when I navigate to http://localhost:3128/jscoverage.html?/index.html I get following error. java.lang.NullPointerException
 at jscover.server.ProxyService.handleProxyRequest(ProxyService.java:376)
 at jscover.server.ProxyService.handleProxyGet(ProxyService.java:366)
 at jscover.server.InstrumentingRequestHandler.handleGet(InstrumentingRequestHandler.java:468)
 at jscover.server.HttpServer.run(HttpServer.java:417)

Comment: You supposed to configure your browser to use localhost:3128 as a proxy and go to `http://localhost:57263/FeatureDev/JavaScriptTestsWithDependencies.aspx` as normal. Please review the instructions in the example and try the selenium-ide-proxy.html sample to familiarise yourself with how it works.